# Communication socket on python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm learn about tcp/ip communication. I make some requirement like this

```
Client 1 -> hardware (1.1.1.1, 62093)
Client 2 -> client.py (12.12.12.12, 5234)
Server 3 -> server.py (12.12.12.12, 5000)
```

`Server` can receive data from **Client 1** and **Client 2** but when I try send data from **Client 2** to **Client1** it can't connected. It's possible to send data from **Client 2** to **Client 1** ? If not possible how do **Client 1** send data to **Client 2** ?

If someone have an idea please tell me, it will be helpful,  Thanks

Comment: Client 1 sends to server, server sends to client 2

Comment: Ok got it, but i don't know how to send to specific ip from server. I used pyton socket . Can you explain send to specific IP from server?

Comment: Client 1 connects server .... client 2 connects server ... server has both clients stored in variable client1 and variable client2 (of coarse since you are the server you will have to store the connections